# how can i count lines in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextarea

I tried using linewarp, but it seems that it won't work. I need to make something that counts the lines of the text you insert in a JTextArea.

Here is my code, until now I am having so much trouble. My program can now count 50 words and when ok is fired it counts the words and the letters and every 50 words it puts a sign of <<50>> or <<100>> or....:

```
package wordscount;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Shady Kamal
 * 
 */

public class WordsCount{

boolean isword;
boolean working;
int words = 0;
int charsa = 0;
int max = 3000;
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(70, 70);
JTextArea wordsText = new JTextArea();
JTextArea charsText = new JTextArea();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fast Reading 50 words - Made by Shady Kamal ©");
JButton launch = new JButton("Start");
JButton fullScreenButton = new JButton("Full Screen");
JLabel charsLabel = new JLabel();
JLabel wordsLabel = new JLabel();
String atext;
Dimension screenDimension= new Dimension();
Timer timer;



public WordsCount(){

    wordsText.setText("Words: " + "\n");
    wordsText.setEditable(false);
    wordsText.setEnabled(true);
    charsText.setText("Letters: " + "\n");
    charsText.setEnabled(true);
    charsText.setEditable(false);
    wordsText.setSize(10, 2);
    charsText.setSize(10, 2);

    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    launch.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int wordsSize = 0;
        words = 0;
        atext = text.getText();
        charsa = atext.length();
        launch.setName("Start - Pressed");

        if(words <= 49){
            launch.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            launch.setEnabled(false);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < charsa; i++) {

            wordsSize++;

            if ( Character.isLetter(atext.charAt(i)) == false ){
                   isword = false;
               }else if (i == 0){
                   isword = true;
               }else if ( Character.isLetter(atext.charAt(i-1)) ){
                   isword = false;
               }else if ( atext.charAt(i-1) == '\'' && i > 1 && 
                          Character.isLetter(atext.charAt(i-2)) ){
                   isword = false;
                }else{
                   isword = true;
                }
            if (isword){
                words++;
                if(words == 50 || words == 50*2 || words == 50*3 || words == 50*4 
                        || words == 50*5 || words == 50*6 || words == 50*7 
                        || words == 50*8 || words == 50*9 || words == 50*10 
                        || words == 50*11 || words == 50*12 || words == 50*13 
                        || words == 50*14 || words == 50*15 || words == 50*16 
                        || words == 50*17 || words == 50*18 || words == 50*19 
                        || words == 50*20 || words == 50*21 || words == 50*22 
                        || words == 50*23 || words == 50*24 || words == 50*25 
                        || words == 50*26 || words == 50*27 || words == 50*28 
                        || words == 50*29 || words == 50*30 || words == 50*31 
                        || words == 50*32 || words == 50*33 || words == 50*34 
                        || words == 50*35 || words == 50*36 || words == 50*37 
                        || words == 50*38 || words == 50*39 || words == 50*40 
                        || words == 50*41 || words == 50*42 || words == 50*43
                        || words == 50*44 || words == 50*45 || words == 50*46 
                        || words == 50*47 || words == 50*48 || words == 50*49 
                        || words == 50*50 || words == 50*51 || words == 50*52
                        || words == 50*53 || words == 50*54 || words == 50*55
                        || words == 50*56 || words == 50*57 || words == 50*58
                        || words == 50*59 || words == max){
                    text.insert(" >>" + words + "<< ", wordsSize);
                }
               }
              }
              System.out.println("Chars: " + charsa);
              System.out.println("Words: " + words);
              wordsText.setText("Words: \n" + words);
              charsText.setText("Letters: \n" + charsa);

            }
       });

    charsLabel.add(charsText);
    wordsLabel.add(wordsText);
    frame.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(wordsText, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(charsText, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(text),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(launch, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""
            + "                                Instructions: \n"
            + "_________________________________________\n"
            + "Just paste text right here in the TextBox\n"
            + "and click the \"Start\" button when your'e ready\n"
            + "the program will do the rest.\n"
            + "PAY ATTENTION!\n"
            + "1)It works only up to 3,000 words Just for \n"
            + "preventing bugs and lags and Making it smoothier and easier to run\n"
            );

    new WordsCount();

}

}
```

Comment: whats the actual problem? It seems to work ok. Under what conditions does it die?

Comment: You can simplify that big "if (words = 50 || words = 50 * 2 ...)" bit by replacing it with "if (words % 50 == 0)", by the way :)

Comment: lines in JTextAreas view <> lines in Document (model for JTextComponents)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found solution:

```
public double countLines(javax.swing.JTextArea textArea, double max_width) {
    javax.swing.text.PlainDocument doc = (javax.swing.text.PlainDocument) textArea.getDocument();
    double counting = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < textArea.getLineCount(); i++) {
        try {
            int start = textArea.getLineStartOffset(i);
            int length = textArea.getLineEndOffset(i) - start; // calculating the length of the line
            // if the width of the line in greater than the max width, the division would return the number of lines
            counting += Math.ceil(textArea.getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont()).stringWidth(doc.getText(start, length)) / max_width);
        } catch (javax.swing.text.BadLocationException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return counting;
}
```

It works in every situation, and calculate it exactly ☺

Answer (score 2):

### Using Stream:

```java
// Count lines without blank lines
int numberLines = text // Text obtained from the getText method of the JTextArea
            .lines() // Get the text line by line
            .filter(line -> !line.isBlank()) // Filter all lines removing empty lines
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // Convert the flattened content to a list
            .size(); // We get the final size being the total number of lines


// Count words of the text
int numberWords = text // Text obtained from the getText method of the JTextArea
            .lines() // Get the text line by line
            .filter(line -> !line.isBlank()) // Filter all lines removing empty lines
            .map(line -> line.replaceAll("^\\s*","")) // Replace all spaces, line breaks, and tabs before the word with an empty string
            .map(line -> line.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")) // Remove all spaces of 2 or more that are repeated or in a row
            .map(line -> line.split(" ")) // Divide each line content by spaces
            .flatMap(Stream::of) // Flatten all word arrays to one
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // Convert the flattened content to a list
            .size(); // We get the final size being the total number of words
```

- They validate that the strings are not empty, that they do not start with a space, apart from eliminating any space repeated more than once, line break or tabulation.

Comment: Maybe you can add per line some information what the line is about.

Comment: Ready, they have been commented line by line with their corresponding action, Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to split the string into lines by splitting on the '\n' character, and just returning the number of lines you get in the result:

```
String[] lines = aText.split('\n');
int lineCount = lines.length;
```

Comment: I can't use that because it just split up the text so sometimes it just writes "he                                                                           <<50>> llo"

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) class for various utility methods. For example:

1. getLInes()
2. getWrappedLines()

depending on your requirement.

```
/*
 *  Return the number of lines of text in the Document
 */
public static int getLines(JTextComponent component)
{
    Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    return root.getElementCount();
}

/*
 *  Return the number of lines of text, including wrapped lines.
 */
public static int getWrappedLines(JTextArea component)
{
    View view = component.getUI().getRootView(component).getView(0);
    int preferredHeight = (int)view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
    int lineHeight = component.getFontMetrics( component.getFont() ).getHeight();
    return preferredHeight / lineHeight;
}
```